# Can't figure out how to use Windows Backup

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup, windows-7-backup

I'm seriously confused.

I tell Windows 7 to back up some files on my `D:\` drive along with my documents from `C:\` onto my `Q:\` drive, and here's what I see, with some questions:

- Every time I change a setting, it seems to go through the entire process again, why? Is there no way to add/remove a folder without going through the entire pain again?
- Is there any way to limit the storage space used?
- My `C:\System Volume Information` folder keeps growing (~ 1GB). Shouldn't it be using just Q:\?
- I can't figure out how to tell Windows, "No, don't back up this file!". Is there any way?
- How would Windows react if all of a sudden I resized and/or moved my partitions? Would my backups still be valid? And what if a drive letter changes?

Comment: Use another backup solution, Windows backup is very limited software.

Comment: @Moab: Right... I'd never given it a try, and since I saw people recommending it all over the place, I thought, why not? Turns out I was right at the beginning. :\

Comment: I like this software...http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this level of configuration, Windows Backup may not be for you. Its general purpose is to keep your grandmother from losing her photos when she does something stupid (sorry gran).

*Every time I change a setting, it seems to go through the entire process again, why? Is there no way to add/remove a folder without going through the entire pain again?*

To my knowledge, Windows Backup is kinda stupid in this respect that it doesn't seem to poll the filesystem for recent writes, but if you add or remove a folder the first thing it does is back up again.

*Is there any way to limit the storage space used?*

[Yes](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/itdojo/prevent-windows-vista-system-restore-from-filling-up-your-hard-drive/1026). (Just for the record it normally limits itself to 30% of the backup drive.)

*My C:\System Volume Information folder keeps growing (~ 1GB). Shouldn't it be using just Q:\?*

It builds and compiles together the backup before copying it over, IIRC.

*How would Windows react if all of a sudden I resized and/or moved my partitions? Would my backups still be valid? And what if a drive letter changes?*

If a little thing like a partition resize could invalidate an entire backup, there's a problem. Besides, Windows backs your files up into a bunch of zip files (and usually a hard disk image) along with some metadata. It identifies the drive by UUID last time I checked, so you might have to reconfigure the location if you move the partition or something.
That said, it's ostensibly not a good idea to repartition your backup drive with backups still on it.

Comment: (1) "may be for you" -> I assume you missed the word "not"?
(2) "it normally limits itself to 30% of the backup drive" --> my backup drive just became full and Backup asked for more space. :\
(3) Thanks for the info, that explains the behavior.

Comment: @Mehrdad 1: Whoops. I almost failed most of my geometry tests with a typo like that :-/. 2: How big is your drive?

Comment: (1) lol, I feel ya. (2) My drive was 10 GB big, and AFAIK even the *data* I was asking it to back up was less than that (around a couple gigs -- mainly my Chrome profile and miscellaneous hand-picked directories)... it was weird.

Comment: @Mehrdad Hm. I assume you disabled the disk image... I would have to say it's just a computer freak, maybe a bug. Probably not worth the time that you could spend setting up SyncToy for your purpose.